# Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] $ then does $ f $ takes the value $\int_{0}^{1} f^{2} (x)dx $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] $  then is it necessary for a continuous function  $f$ to takes the value $ \int_{0}^{1} f^{2} (x)dx  $ for some point inside $ [0,1] $

I think it can be prove rigorously that this need not to satisfy using fixed point theorem arguments.. But I Stuck with it..!!

Comment: This is clearly false if we do not assume $f$ to be continuous. Please add a proper context and some actual attempts.

Comment: sorry my fault .. what if f is continuous

Comment: Then it is clearly false by considering the constant function $f(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

Comment: Can you prove this without giving examples.. What i am trying to get what will happen if a continuous function takes such a value

Comment: If f is surjective , then it's true.

Comment: If $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is continuous, it attains the value $\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2\,dx}$ (its *quadratic* mean value) by the mean value property of continuous functions. Any statement that is dimensionally incorrect stands no chance of holding in general.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio .. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly not take $f(x) = 1/2$

Then $\int_{0}^{1}f^2(x)dx = 1/4$ but $f$ does not take this value.

Comment: @MasterX A false statement cannot be proved.

Comment: @MasterX What do you mean what will happen? Lots of things could happen; f could be constant, f could be the identity, f could be discontinuous. What would you like to know about?